# Silverstripe Restfulapi configuration

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I try the [Restfulapi](https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi) addon for silverstripe 4 and my configuration is:

```
integre\About:
  api_access: true
integre\Home:
  api_access: true
Image:
  api_access: true
File:
  api_access: true
integre\Theatre:
  api_access: true
# RestfulAPI config
Colymba\RESTfulAPI\RESTfulAPI:
  authentication_policy: false
  access_control_policy: 'ACL_CHECK_CONFIG_AND_MODEL'
  cors:
    Enabled: true
    Allow-Origin: '*'
    Allow-Headers: '*'
    Allow-Methods: 'OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE'
    Max-Age: 86400
```

but when i try http://localhost/integre/api/Theatre/1 i receive
{
"code": 400,
"message": "Model does not exist. Received 'Theatre'."
}

how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a namespaced class and not correctly configuring it to be used in the API, so it's not resolving correctly. Looking at [`DefaultQueryHandler`](https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi/blob/master/src/QueryHandlers/DefaultQueryHandler.php), you need to [define a class name map for this](https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi/blob/master/src/QueryHandlers/DefaultQueryHandler.php#L116-L120):

```
Colymba\RESTfulAPI\QueryHandlers\DefaultQueryHandler:
  models:
    Theatre: integre\Theatre
```

This tells the query handler to load `integre\Theatre` when it is asked for a `Theatre` model. Note that your Image and File references in your configuration are also missing their namespaces.

Comment: I try `?__limit[]=count&__limit[]=offset` to paginate but it doesn't show the paginate Json at the end, how to receive the Paginate Json?

Comment: I have no idea, but that sounds like a different question :-)